# Pysimplegui: get event source without a key

Tags: python, event-handling, pysimplegui

I'm making a Calendar app for my workplace. I want to be able to assign shift (in manager mode) or request & block shifts (in worker mode).

In order for the latter part to be convenient, I want the Text element for each shift to be clickable, making it colored red for block for example.

My problem is that the only way I know to create so many identifiable clickable elements is by assigning a different key to each of them, and there are many shift elements each month (
>120).

Is there any other way to know which element evoked the event? Is there anything else I'm missing? I feel like there has to be a more elegant, maintainable way then the one mentioned above.

I'll paste my code for generating the calendar in case it helps.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import json
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('DarkGrey15')   # Add a touch of color

min_weeks, max_weeks = (4, 6)
'Dec']
weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
workers = ['worker1', 'worker2', 'worker3', 'worker4', 'worker5']
shift_emoji = {'full': '', 'day': '☀️', 'night': ''}
selector_key = 'MonthSelectorKey'
browser_key = 'JsonBrowserKey'

worker_mode_button_title = ['create request file', 'back to shift assignment']
worker_mode_key = 'WorkerModeKey'
worker_requests = ['block', 'request', 'cancel']
worker_requests_default = worker_requests[0]
worker_requests_key = 'WorkerRequestsKey'
exoprt_key = 'ExportKey'

class StateClass:
    def __init__(self, month_start = datetime.now().replace(day= 1)) -> None:
        self.blocks = {}
        
        self.month_start = month_start
        if month_start.month < 12:
            self.month_start = month_start.replace(month= month_start.month+1)
        else:
            self.month_start = month_start.replace(year= month_start.year+1, month= 1)
        self.month_range = calendar.monthrange(month_start.year, month_start.month)
        self.worker_mode = False

state = StateClass()

def CreateShiftUi(text: str):
    return [sg.Text(text, expand_x=True, enable_events=True), sg.Combo(workers, enable_events=True)]

def CreateWorkdayUi():
    return [CreateShiftUi(emo) for emo in shift_emoji.values()]

def CreateWorkdayFrame(day: int):
    return sg.Frame(day, CreateWorkdayUi())

def CreateWeekRow(start_day: int):
    return [CreateWorkdayFrame(start_day+i) for i in range(7)]

def WorkdaySetEnable(workday_frame: sg.Frame, f_enable: bool):
    for row in workday_frame.Rows:
        row[-1].update('', values= workers, disabled= not f_enable)

def WeekSetEnable(week: list[sg.Frame], f_enable: bool, until: int=6):
    for workday in week[:until+1]:
        WorkdaySetEnable(workday, f_enable)
    for workday in week[until+1:]:
        WorkdaySetEnable(workday, not f_enable)

def WeekSetHidden(week_row: list[sg.Frame], f_hide: bool):
    if week_row[0].visible != f_hide:
        return
    for workday in week_row:
        workday.update(visible= not f_hide)

def OnMonthChanged():
    new_year = month_row[0].get()
    new_month = month_row[1].get()
    if new_month == state.month_start.month and new_year == state.month_start.year:
        return
    state.month_start = state.month_start.replace(year= new_year, month= new_month)
    ResetCalendar()

def CalendarFrame(day_in_month):
    day = day_in_month + state.month_range[0]
    return calendar_layout[day//7][day%7]

def ResetCalendar():
    global calendar_layout
    state.month_range = calendar.monthrange(state.month_start.year, state.month_start.month)
    start_weekday = (state.month_range[0]+1) % 7
    
    weeks_in_month = (state.month_range[1]+start_weekday+6) // 7
    for week in calendar_layout[min_weeks : weeks_in_month]:
        WeekSetHidden(week, False)
    for week in calendar_layout[weeks_in_month : max_weeks]:
        WeekSetHidden(week, True)
        WeekSetEnable(week, False)
    
    # Disable out-of-month days
    WeekSetEnable(calendar_layout[0], False, start_weekday-1)
    for week in calendar_layout[1 : weeks_in_month-1]:
        WeekSetEnable(week, True)
    end_weekday = (start_weekday + state.month_range[1] - 1) % 7
    WeekSetEnable(calendar_layout[weeks_in_month-1], True, end_weekday)
    
    # Renumber days in month
    for i in range(1, 1+state.month_range[1]):
        CalendarFrame(i).update(i)
    prev_month = (state.month_start.month-2)%12 + 1
    prev_month_len = calendar.monthrange(state.month_start.year - int(prev_month == 12), prev_month)[1]
    for i in range(start_weekday):
        calendar_layout[0][i].update(prev_month_len - start_weekday + i + 1)
    for i in range(end_weekday+1,7):
        calendar_layout[weeks_in_month-1][i].update(i-end_weekday)

def ApplyBlockfile(block_file):
    # Read the Json file
    with open(block_file) as json_file:
        block_data = json.load(json_file)
        # Validate worker's name
        name = block_data['worker_name'].capitalize()
        if not name in workers:
            print(name + " doesn't appear on you list")
            return
        # Remove from relevant Combos
        for blocking in block_data['blockings'].items():
            blocked_day = int(blocking[0])
            blocked_frame = CalendarFrame(blocked_day)
            for blocked_shift in blocking[1]:
                shift_type = list(shift_emoji).index(blocked_shift)
                shift_combo: sg.Combo = blocked_frame.Rows[shift_type][-1]
                new_list = shift_combo.Values.copy()
                if name in new_list:
                    new_list.remove(name)
                    shift_combo.update(values= new_list)

def OnWorkerMode():
    new_mode = not state.worker_mode
    state.worker_mode = new_mode
    window[worker_mode_key].update(worker_mode_button_title[new_mode])
    window[worker_requests_key].update(visible= new_mode)
    if new_mode:
        pass
    else:
        window[worker_requests_key].update(worker_requests_default)

calendar_layout = [CreateWeekRow(1+7*j) for j in range(max_weeks)]
month_row = [sg.Spin([i for i in range(2020,2100)], state.month_start.year),
             sg.Combo([i for i in range(1,13)],state.month_start.month, key=selector_key, enable_events=True),
             sg.FilesBrowse('Browse', enable_events= True, file_types= (("JSON", "*.json"),), target= browser_key),
             sg.Input(key= browser_key, visible= False, enable_events= True, expand_x= True),
             sg.Button(worker_mode_button_title[0], key=worker_mode_key, enable_events= True),
             sg.Combo(worker_requests, worker_requests_default, key=worker_requests_key, visible=False, enable_events=True),
             sg.Button('export', key= exoprt_key)]
weekday_titles = [sg.Text(weekdays[i],expand_x=True, justification='center') for i in range(len(weekdays))]
layout = [
    month_row,
    weekday_titles,
    calendar_layout,
    ]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
ResetCalendar()

# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel': # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    if event == selector_key:
        OnMonthChanged()
        continue
    if event == browser_key:
        for block_file in values[browser_key].split(';'):
            ApplyBlockfile(block_file)
        continue
    if event == worker_mode_key:
        OnWorkerMode()
        continue
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set tuple value for option `key` and also `enable_events=True` for all Text elements.

Demo code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Text(sg.Text):

    mark = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def select(self):
        if Text.mark:
            Text.mark.update(background_color=sg.theme_background_color())
        Text.mark = self
        self.update(background_color="blue")

font = ("Courier New", 16, "bold")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [[Text(f"({row}, {col})", enable_events=True, key=('Text', row, col)) for col in range(7)] for row in range(6)]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, background_color='green', finalize=True)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif isinstance(event, tuple) and event[0]=='Text':
        window[event].select()

window.close()
```

[image]

Another way is to use the `window.AllKeysDict` and `window.user_bind_event.widget` to find which element evoked the event, but you still need to assign keys for those elements.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Text(sg.Text):

    mark = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def select(self):
        if Text.mark:
            Text.mark.update(background_color=sg.theme_background_color())
        Text.mark = self
        self.update(background_color="blue")

font = ("Courier New", 16, "bold")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [[Text(f"({row}, {col})", enable_events=True, key=(row, col)) for col in range(7)] for row in range(6)]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, background_color='green', finalize=True)
widget_to_element = {value.widget:value for value in window.AllKeysDict.values()}
window.bind("<Button-1>", "Click")

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Click":
        widget = window.user_bind_event.widget
        if widget in widget_to_element:
            element = widget_to_element[widget]
            if isinstance(element, Text):
                element.select()

window.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That'd make it way more manageable

Comment: Tuples as keys is very helpful in many situations.  If you've got a lot of elements to manage, they're great for that as you can see.  They're also good if you want to group keys that are in a "category" like "events send from a thread", or layouts in Tabs that look similar (use the tab name as part of tuple... ("Tab1", "-INPUT-").

Comment: You can also access tuple events using `event[0]` safely without testing to see if it's a tuple.  For example, if a thread sends events like `("-FROM THREAD-", text_to_output)`, then you can check to see if a thread event has happened with the statement `if event[0] == '-FROM THREAD-': `